# error when trying to build the apk for my app

Tags: android

I am getting the following error when building the apk for my app to run on my cellphone, im not sure where the actually error is so im not sure how to solve it.

[image: error]

I have looked through my code and I am not seeing any errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Here is some of my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){         
   View v = convertView; 
   if(v == null){ 
     LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); 
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false); 
   }  
    return v; 
 }
```

Comment: The error says you return or process something called ``bridgeContext`` where an Activity is expected. So look for variables of type BridgeContext in your getView method.

Comment: Can you post your code please? It will help us find the error.

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
        }

        return v;
    }  this is the getview code

Comment: @HayleeLutchman In the future, you should add the code to you question, and format it.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai i will do so, sorry im just new to stack overflow

Comment: @HayleeLutchman No worries. I figured I'd point it out. Some people on here are quite a bit less forgiving than I am ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();`. You can't cast `context` to an activity. For that call you should be doing:

```
context.getLayoutInflater();
```

If that doesn't work (because you are in a fragment, or outside the activity) then do:

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

You can also use `getApplicationContext`, which will grab the context from anywhere in the app, verses the above `getActivity` which will get the context for the current activity:

```
getApplicationContext().getLayoutInflater();
```

Either way, you can't cast the context into an Activity.

Comment: I have tried using all three and it is giving me an error on 'getLayoutInflactor();'

Comment: You need to use `getLayoutInflater()`, not `getLayoutInflactor()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Error message:                                                                                                      Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

Answer (score 0):

> Two Solutions one for getting application context using **getApplicationContext()**
>   , second one in the adapter constructor contains this **(Context context, int res, List obj)** declare a private variable of type context and assign it in adapter like this this.context = context;

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){         
   View v = convertView; 
   if(v == null){ 
     LayoutInflater inflater = (getApplicationContext()).getLayoutInflater(); 
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false); 
   }  
    return v; 
 }
```

Comment: If my answer is right and helpful for you and others so you must vote up and mark it right...